# Piecewise Cubic Hermite Interpolating Polynomial (PCHIP) for given data in MATLAB and then finding area

Tags: matlab, interpolation, area

**Hello friends**

I am trying to do Piecewise Cubic Hermite Interpolation on the data given below in MATLAB and then I want to get the area covered by the polynomials with x axis. I think, I am misunderstanding the meaning of coefficients returned by pchip command, but not sure. Does anyonw know what could be the problem?

```
x = [5.8808 6.5137 7.1828 7.8953];

y = [31.2472 33.9977 36.7661 39.3567];

pp = pchip(x,y)
```

If I see see pp,it gives pp as

```
   form: 'pp'
    breaks: [5.8808 6.5137 7.1828 7.8953]
     coefs: [3x4 double]
    pieces: 3
     order: 4
       dim: 1
```

and pp.coefs are

```
-0.0112 -0.1529 4.4472 31.2472

-0.3613 0.0884 4.2401 33.9977

-0.0422 -0.3028 3.8731 36.7661
```

I think these are the polynomials representing the three intervals

```
[5.8808:6.5137],

[6.5137:7.1828],

[7.1828:7.8953]
```

But when I find the y values corresponding to x values using these polynomials, it gives wrong values.

It gives negative y values for second polynomial . Even third polynomial do not seem to satisfy the points.

I used these commands for obtaining the values

For example:- (for second polynomial)

```
xs = linspace(6.5137, 7.1828, 200);

y = polyval(pp.coefs(2,:),xs);

plot(xs,y)
```

I want to find the area under the curve covered by this plot, that's why I am trying to find the polynomial. Is there any other way to do it or if anyone could find the problem in the commands that I am using, please let me know.

*Thanks*

***Bhomik Luthra***

Comment: You may want to try [`ppval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ppval.html) instead of `polyval`.

Answer (score 2):

As hinted in the comments by Schorsch, you should probably use the function `ppval` instead of `polyval`. Indeed, these two functions have different goals even if they are related:

- `polyval` can be used to interpret a vector as a polynomial, where each entry in the vector is a coefficient in the polynomial. With this function, the polynomial cannot be defined piecewise.
- `ppval` lets you evaluate a piecewise polynomial. The pieces of the polynomial are defined between the breaks (as you correctly guessed). Then, between two breaks, the coefficients of the polynomials are given for a polynomial in `(x-left)` (left being the left side of the considered interval), not `x`.

**To achieve you goal, you have then two equivalent solutions:**

1. Use `ppval` instead of `polyval` in you command (I would recommand that solution):

   ```
   xs = linspace(6.5137, 7.1828, 200);
   y = ppval(pp,xs);
   plot(xs,y)
   ```
2. Use properly the polyval function:

   ```
   xs = linspace(6.5137, 7.1828, 200);
   y = polyval(pp.coefs(2,:),xs-6.5137);
   plot(xs,y)
   ```

Hope this helps!